# Variable based on Variable SSRS with Oracle Native connection

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have an SSRS paginated report where users need the ability to pick and choose which variables they want the report run with. For example, the query looks something like:

```
`SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE 1=1
AND CUSTOMER_NUMBER = ?
AND CUSTOMER_STATE = ?`
```

The users need the ability to plug in a CUSTOMER_NUMBER parameter OR a CUSTOMER_STATE parameter. So for instance if they decide to provide a customer number, "x", the query would read:

```
`SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE 1=1
AND CUSTOMER_NUMBER = x`
```

leaving the "AND CUSTOMER_STATE = ?" line blank. In SQL server I've been able to achieve this by using something like the query below.

```
`DECLARE @cust_t as varchar(MAX)
IF @cust <> ''
SET @cust_t = 'AND CUSTOMER_NUMBER IN (' + '''''' + REPLACE(@cust,',',''''',''''') + '''''' + ')';
ELSE
SET @cust_t = ' ';

DECLARE @state_t as varchar(MAX)
IF @state <> ''
SET @state_t = 'AND CUSTOMER_STATE IN (' + '''''' + REPLACE(@state,',',''''',''''') + '''''' + ')';
ELSE
SET @state_t = ' ';

DECLARE @SQL as varchar(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE 1=1
' + @cust_t + '
' + @state_t ;

EXEC(@SQL)`
```

Where the user provides @cust and/or @state. I just can't figure out how to do this with a native Oracle connection. Or if there's a better/easier way, let me know.

Comment: is dynamic sql out of the question? you could build the query string dependent on the parms and than execute that query using `execute immediate`.

Comment: FYI: in SQL Server you could so it simpler than dynamic sql with `SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE 1=1 
AND (CUSTOMER_NUMBER = @cust OR @cust IS NULL)
 AND (CUSTOMER_STATE = @state OR @state IS NULL)` I don't know what the oracle equivalent is but that would be my approach.

Comment: @Miguel dynamic sql can be used. I've tried using an "execute immediate" function but couldn't get it to work. If you know of a good way to convert what I have into an Oracle execute immediate statement, please provide an example if you can.